# SonarQube on http:/localhost:9000 cannot be reached

Tags: sonarqube, localhost, port

I'm running SonarQube on CentOS 7. It is correctly running on the terminal, but if I try to access it through the browser (http:/localhost:9000 or http:/localhost:9001 ) it can't be reached. Can someone help me?

```
    [root@192 logs]# systemctl status sonarqube
● sonarqube.service - SonarQube service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since ven 2022-10-07 12:48:37 CEST; 3s ago
  Process: 23246 ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23275 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 23298 (java)
    Tasks: 43
   CGroup: /system.slice/sonarqube.service
           ├─23298 java -Xms8m -Xmx32m --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens...
           └─23321 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.1.1-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -XX:ErrorFile...

ott 07 12:48:37 192.168.1.24 systemd[1]: Starting SonarQube service...
ott 07 12:48:37 192.168.1.24 sonar.sh[23275]: /usr/bin/java
ott 07 12:48:37 192.168.1.24 sonar.sh[23275]: Starting SonarQube...
ott 07 12:48:37 192.168.1.24 systemd[1]: Started SonarQube service.
```

[Unable to connect localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJvUF.png)